# Get maximum value from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray

How can I get a maximum value from an NSMutableArray. Values are stores as NSString in array as below

```
for(int counter=0; counter<[datesArray count];counter++)
{
    glass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[dbhandler todayData:currentDate] floatValue]];
    [graphGlassesArray addObject:glass];
}
```

Array name is `graphGlassesArray`.

Comment: Have you tried looping through and storing the largest value you've encountered so far in a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the max value from an array using:

```
NSNumber* max = [graphGlassesArray valueForKeyPath:@"max.self"];
float maxFloat = [max floatValue]
```

Comment: you were just a second faster than me... I'm not posting this idea then.

Answer (score 1):

You should also try to use *Key Value Coding* (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html). To obrain the max in a NSArray you can do `[array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.attribute"]`. Try to look at this link http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/.

Answer (score 0):

```
float max = 0.f;
for(int counter=0; counter<[datesArray count];counter++)
{
    glass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[dbhandler todayData:currentDate] floatValue]];
    [graphGlassesArray addObject:glass];
    if(max < [[dbhandler todayData:currentDate] floatValue]) {
        max = [[dbhandler todayData:currentDate] floatValue];
    }
}
```

Try with this

Answer (score 0):

Try by sorting the mutable array

```
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)]; 
NSString *maxValue = [[graphGlassesArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:desc]] objectAtIndex:0];
[desc release];
```